# TypeError: Field 'classroom' expected a number but got (4,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have an array of arrays. Each of the nested arrays contains information about a student. I'm then iterating over it and saving each of the arrays into a student object and persisting that into my DB.

```
students = [
    ["James", "Smith", 4, 10],
    # more students here
]

for s in students:
    student = Student()
    student.first_name = s[0],
    student.last_name = s[1],
    student.classroom = s[2],
    student.grade1 = s[3],
    student.save()
```

The field `classroom` in the `Student` class is defines as a `FloatField`.

I'm getting following error:

> TypeError: Field 'classroom' expected a number but got (4,).

What can be the cause for this?

EDIT 1: typo

Comment: The problem is the trailing commas on all your variable lines. You're literally setting the value to `4,`

Comment: using float(s[2]) did not work.
@match how can I change the line to make it work?

Comment: Remove the comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trailing commas create tuples.

```
student.first_name = s[0],
```

Should be

```
student.first_name = s[0]
```

You can read more about that weird syntax here --
https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1
> items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty
> tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with
> one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not
> sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but
> effective.

Answer (score 1):

As @match has said, you have trailing commas when setting the values of your variables. Remove those and you should be good. For example:

```
student.first_name = s[0]
student.last_name = s[1]
student.classroom = s[2]
student.grade1 = s[3]
student.save()
```

No commas between setting the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code but i think you mean to do something like this :

```
s = [
    ["James", "Smith", 4, 10],
    # more students here
]

class Student:
 
    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name,classroom,grade):
        """ Create a new point at the origin """
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.classroom = classroom
        self.grade = grade


student = Student(s[0][0],s[0][1],s[0][2],s[0][3])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(vars(student))
```